# JQuery Ajax post method is not working in laravel

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I want to save an image and two text field using JQuery,Ajax. here, i'm using bootstrap modal. But when I submit the modal form it's show **MethodNotAllowedHttpException** Exception.

My Ajax Method.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#advisoradd').on('submit',function(){
        var name=$('#adname').val();
        var title=$('#adtitle').val();
        var img=$('#adfile').val();


       $.ajax({

        url:"{{route('add.advisor')}}",
        type:'post',
        data:{
            '_token':"{{csrf_token()}}",
            'name':name,
            'title':title,
            'img':img,
        },

        success:function(data)
        {
            console.log(data);
        }

       });

   });

});
```

My view Modal code.

```
 <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            {{csrf_field()}}
                              <div class="form-group">
                               <div class="img_upload_team">
                                <button class="btn">+</button>
          <input type="file" name="myfile" id="adfile">
                                  </div>
                                    <h2>Add A Profile Photo</h2>
                                    <p>Click “+” Sign to Add</p>
                                     </div>
                                     <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="adname" class="form-control" id="adname" placeholder="Name">
                                      </div>
                                       <div class="form-group">
           <input type="text" name="adtitle" class="form-control" id="adtitle" placeholder="Title">
                                        </div>

                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn_modal_submit" id="advisoradd">Add</button>
         </form>
```

My controller and Route for this Request.

```
 public function addadvisor(Request $request)
{
    $advisor=new Advisor();
    $advisor->name=$request->name;
    $advisor->title=$request->title;

    $file = $request->file('img') ;
    $fileName = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $destinationpath=public_path().'/images/';
    $file->move($destinationpath,$fileName);
    $advisor->image=$fileName;
    $advisor->save();
    return response()->json($advisor);
}
```

**Route::post('/advisor','ImageController@addadvisor')->name('add.advisor');**

Comment: A `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` implies that the server is not expecting a POST request to the URL you've specified

Comment: I'm guessing that you mean "JQuery Ajax post method is _**not**_ working in laravel"?

Comment: Yes, **Magnus**

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - That value isn't case sensitive.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson was not talking about case sensitivity, but the key. Anyway, I just checked the doc and `type` is an alias of `method`. My bad!

Comment: @Karl-AndréGagnon - Missed your updated comment :-)

Comment: You have `.on('submit', ...` on the button. Change it to `.on('click', ...`. Buttons don't have a "submit" event, forms do. Right now, you're posting the form "the old fashioned" way and since you don't have a `method` on your actual form, it defaults to `GET`. You should also add a preventDefault() in the callback to stop the form from posting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed up button and form events. Buttons don't have a `submit` event, forms do. Since you're adding the event on the button, change it to `click`.

We should also add a `preventDefault()` to stop the button from submitting the form.
(We could also add the `type="button"` attribute on the button element to stop it from submitting the form).

This should work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // Add a 'click' event instead of an invalid 'submit' event.
    $('#advisoradd').on('click', function(e) {
        // Prevent the button from submitting the form
        e.preventDefault();

        // The rest of your code
    });
});
```